# Are fossils in slate 3 dimensional or does the slate split open at the weakest point where the flat imprint of the fossil is found?

Tags: fossils

In this picture you see a fossil of an Ammonite. When you break a slate with a hammer it will fall apart so sometimes you can find a fossil. But is this fossil only there in the slate just at the place where the slate is split apart (so the fossil is actually flat) or is this fossil present in a many layers of the slate which actually gives a three dimensional presentation of the fossil so the place where the slate splits open isn't that important.

http://c7.alamy.com/comp/GJMNHA/fossil-slate-texture-GJMNHA.jpg

Comment: It depends on the mode of preservation. Those look like they retain some three dimensional structure to me.